# Prevent pseudo-element content from changing color on hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When I mouse over the links "EN | FR", then all characters including the pipe character ' | ' change color to blue.

```css
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
a.language {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
}
a.language:last-child:before {
  content: ' | ';
}
```

```html
 <a class="language" href="/en">EN</a>
<a class="language" href="/fr">FR</a>
```

I want to achieve that only the link EN and FR turns to blue on mouse over except the color of the pipe character ' | ' that is between them.

I'm looking for something like:

```
a.language:last-child:before:hover {
    color: grey;
}
```

to keep the pipe character ' | ' grey.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:

Thanks to Paulie_D I have a working [JSfiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/qzfrx0wy/)

Comment: You should just put the pipe directly into your HTML between the two anchor tags. If you do it this way, the pipe will be underlined and it will also be clickable(leading to the french language href).

Comment: yeah, that's the easy way. But the list items are generated dynamically and i can't modify the html so i have to do it with css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
 a.language:last-child:hover::before {
   color: red;
 }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/numpnz4t/)

Or just declare a color for the pseudo-element directly and let specificty win the fight for you.

```
 a.language:last-child::before {
   content: ' | ';
   color:red;
 }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/kprwgrph/)

Comment: Thank you very much Paulie_D, I updated your JSfiddle Demo to match my use case more: https://jsfiddle.net/qzfrx0wy/

Answer (score 3):

Just add the color you want to the existing `::before` declaration:

```
a.language:last-child::before {
      content: ' | ';
      color: gray;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r90s8mfn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply insert the pipe character as a regular character between the links and not have any CSS rule for it:

```
<a class="language" href="/en">EN</a> | <a class="language" href="/fr">FR</a>
```

Comment: yeah, that's the easy way. But the list items are generated dynamically and i can't modify the html so i have to do it with css.